# python - reading serial data sent by stm

Tags: python, serial-port

I've created connection with python to stm32 usb port, and wanted to execute some actions while the certain button is pressed. (one transmit "1" and the other transmit "0"). Why this solution is not working as i wanted?

```
def read():
while True:
    if ser.read(1) == 0:
            print "Zero received" 
            report.send(SET_LEFT())
    if ser.read(1) == 1:
            report.send(SET_RIGHT())
t = threading.Thread(target = read, name = 'thread1')
t.start()
```

Here is serial initialization and signal_handler function that close port connection.

```
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM7',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=0)


def signal_handler(signal, frame):
       ser.close()
       sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```

The error that i receive when i close connection with "crtl + c" is

```
Exception in thread thread1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "C:\usbpy\usb_send.py", line 27, in read
if ser.read() == 0:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 269, in 
read
win32.ResetEvent(self._overlapped_read.hEvent)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hEvent'
```

It seems that the button are not detected during executing main program, when i checked the connection and data that i received with another python program the result was: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WOM0.jpg)

Best Regards

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about not working? One thing that comes to mind off the bet: if that `read` is anything like other `read` methods, it'd yield a `str` (or `bytes`) and hence always evaluate to `False` testing equivalence with an `int`.

Comment: The data that i transmit with stm32f4's buttons are "0" and "1" bit value. Here is an illustration of data received by port COM7 and displayed in python. [link](https://imgur.com/a/ISqVkp0). When i receive "0" or "1" i want to execute SET_LEFT or SET_RIGHT function. And by not working I mean [link](https://imgur.com/a/YODa1KX) - it doesn't  detect the data received by port COM7 - "True" mean that threading is on.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hEvent' means that the function above is not working properly, and im wondering why .

Comment: Please, add that information to the question (as text, not image) as well as how `ser` got instantiated, because the "doesn't work" apparently happens when `read` is being for it as something is `None` where something else with a specific attribute is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created 2 variables:

```
flag_1 = 0
flag_2 = 0
```

If button is pressed im changing the flags value:

```
def read():

    while True:
        global flaga_1
        global flaga_2
        a=ser.read()
        if a == '0':
                flaga_1 = 1
        elif a == '1':
                flaga_2 = 1

t = threading.Thread(target = read, name = 'thread1')
t.start()
```

and in while loop im detecting the flag value change - execute function and set flags value back to "0"

```
if flaga_1 == 1:
          report.send(SET_LEFT())
          flaga_1 = 0

elif flaga_2 == 1:
          report.send(SET_RIGHT())
          flaga_2 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else your read function needs fixing. The ser.read(1) value must be stored in a variable because you need to make multiple comparisons with the data received in that one call - as you have coded it, if the first compare with 1 is false another ser.read(1) (i.e. different dat) is made and compared with 0, and also not having the input stored in a variable means you can’t debug it by e.g. printing the received value. Don’t understand why trying to debug it didn’t make you store the ser.read(1) returned value in a variable so you could print it.

Sorry can’t test this code but it should look something like this:

`def read()
    while True:
        Thisinput = ser.read(1)
        print “received”,Thisinput
        if Thisinput == ‘0’:
            ...
        elif Thisinput == ‘1’:
            ...
        else:
            print ‘Input not recognized:%s’%(input)
            raise Exception(“Invalid input %s”%(Thisinput) )`